# error: cannot find symbol login.render(form(Login.class))

Tags: java, scala, playframework

i was trying to do this tutorial here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide4

but after adding this method to my "Application.java" class, i have the problem,
that the variable "login" cannot be found:

```
public static Result login() {
    return ok(
      login.render(form(Login.class))
    );
}
```

afters searching the internet, what i might be doing wrong, i found several suggestions, like i might have forgotten to create the login view , which in my case is called: "login.scala.html". Maybe i have named it wrong?! i don't know,

i tried the "$ clean" command and "$ compile" command in the play console, but still while,trying to compile the project it throws this error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol: method form(Class(Login.class))
symbol: method form(Class<Login>)
location: class Appplication
```

any ideas what might be the reason for this error?

Comment: okay found the mistake. this line of code makes the difference:     import static play.data.Form.*;

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add "views.html" before "login.render..."

So the right code should look like as follows (if you maintained the proposed file structure from the play framework documentation):

```
public static Result login() {
    return ok(
      view.html.login.render(form(Login.class))
    );
}
```

and add of course the right imports (you noticed that already :) )